# 2-Legged to Google via oAuth DevDefined (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, 2-legged

Has anyone been able to get oAuth working with the gMail feed using the DevDefined oAuth library?

I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to get this working.  Seems like I either get a 401, or 411 returned.

I used [this](http://www.markerstudio.com/technical/2009/09/net-oauth-sample-working-with-justintv/) as a template, but it doesnt appear to be as easy as entering in the google token endpoints

```
string OAuthRequestTokenUri = "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken";
string OAuthAuthorizeToken = "https://www.google.com/accounts/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken";
string OAuthGetAccessToken = "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken";
```

Any help would be awesome :)

Thanks,

Steve